# Please Guide how to write this code in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table named `Questions` having `2000 questions`, I'm using `MySql` database and `Codeigniter`, what I want is to `select 10 PERCENT questions of total 2000 with a query` in Codeigniter.

Comment: What  you have tried so far? Post that too within your question?

Comment: start doing your query before doing it on codeigniter. That would make your work easier

Comment: basically you want to grab 200 records of the 2000 you have?

Comment: $query = $this->db->get('Questions', 200);

Comment: but i need to set a query to get percent please, i dont want exact 200, but percentage to be set in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Controller**

```
public function FunctionName()
{
    $result = $this>model_name->get_question();
    print_r($result);
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function get_question()
{
    #get all question count
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM question");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);  # returns 2000

    $limit = ($count/100)*10;  # returns 200

    # select only limited question which set with $limit
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM question LIMIT $limit");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result
}
```

Comment: Dear i check this and reply you soon thank you

Comment: follow the order i have posetd

Comment: MAN ! you are great, Thank you ! Solved

Comment: @FarrukhBaig happy to help :)

Comment: i have ques_id, question and chapter field in questions table. 
questions table have 2000 questions and 70 questions have field chapter = 1 , 280 questions have field chapter = 2 and so on 10 chapters holding data of 2000 questions. 
Now , i need that each chapter should get 10% questions... Please suggest your kind guidance by code.
Thanks